# Image and text inside of <a> tag

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

This is the html asp.net generated (with some client-identifying details removed)

In Windows XP / IE 7 clicking on the image does nothing.  Click on the text executes the hyperlink.  Right-clicking anywhere and then selecting `open in new window` or `open` also works.

In other browsers, it all works as expected.

Is there anything simple anyone can see that I could do to this to get it to work correctly in IE7?

```
<div id="hdrXXX">                      
            <a id="ctl00_XXX" title="XXX" class="hdrXXX" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
                 <div style="float:left;display: block;"> 
                    <img id="ctl00_XXX" src="Images/XXX.png" style="border-width:0px;" />
                </div>
                <div style="float:left; display: block; padding:15px 0 0 0;"> 
                    <span id="XXX">Some text right here</span>

                </div>
            </a>  
       </div>
```

Comment: You can only put block-level elements inside anchor elements with HTML5 and browser support is still a bit iffy on it. IE7 obviously does not support this.

Comment: @animuson - can you add that as an answer?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can only put block-level elements inside anchor elements with HTML5 and browser support is still a bit iffy on it. IE7 obviously does not support this.

You don't need to use division to do this:

```
<div id="hdrXXX">                      
    <a id="ctl00_XXX" title="XXX" class="hdrXXX" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
        <img id="ctl00_XXX" src="Images/XXX.png" style="border: 0; float: left; margin-right: 15px" /> 
        <span id="XXX">Some text right here</span>
    </a>  
</div>
```

This should work to the same effect...

Comment: read: "You can only put block-level elements inside anchor elements *if you are using* HTML5"

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the divs, as the img tag and span are naturally display-inline. Add display block, float left if you need margins right to the tags themselves as supposed to adding divs. Also, to the anchor tag, add overflow:hidden (if you use floats), so that it takes up the total space of the two child elements.

Answer (score 2):

Because of your floats, the anchor collapses. Also, you can't put block level elements `<div/>` inside inline elements `<a/>`.

Keeping with the non-W3C code you've got there, you'd need to clear your floats with this code right before the closing `</a>`

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

You'll want to probably create a class called `.clear` and move the styles to that. Here's an example from my site:

```
.clear-fix {
clear: both !important;
display: block !important;
font-size: 0 !important;
line-height: 0 !important;
border: none !important;
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
list-style: none !important;
}
```

A better way to do your code which is W3C compliant is the following:

```
<div id="hdrXXX">                      
    <a id="ctl00_XXX" title="XXX" class="hdrXXX" href="http://google.com" target="_blank">
        <span style="float:left;display: block;"> 
            <img id="ctl00_XXX" src="Images/XXX.png" style="border-width:0px;" />
        </span>
        <span style="float:left; display: block; padding:15px 0 0 0;"> 
            <span id="XXX">Some text right here</span>
        </span>
        <span class="clear-fix"></span>
    </a>  
</div>
```