# Add Links to Images in a Script

Tags: javascript

This script replaces the background of the DIV 'middle' with the images listed in the array. Currently the script works perfect but I want to be able to assign a link to each image, tried just replacing with  but then the image doesn't show up nor does the link work.

```
<script>
var images=new Array('/images/home/imgone.jpg', '/images/home/imgtwo.jpg', '/images/home/imgthree.jpg', '/images/home/imgfour.jpg', '/images/home/imgfive.jpg');
var nextimage=0;
doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow(){
if(nextimage>=images.length){nextimage=0;}
$('.middle')
.css('background-image','url("'+images[nextimage++]+'")')
.fadeIn(500,function(){
    setTimeout(doSlideshow,5000);
});
}
</script>
```

What I'm looking for is something like this.

```
<script> 
var images=new Array('/images/home/imgone.jpg', '/images/home/imgtwo.jpg', '/images/home/imgthree.jpg', '/images/home/imgfour.jpg', '/images/home/imgfive.jpg'); To: var images=new Array('<a href="linkone"><img src="/images/home/imgone.jpg"</a>', '<a href="linktwo"><img src="/images/home/imgtwo.jpg"</a>', '<a href="linkthree"><img src="/images/home/imgthree.jpg"</a>', '<a href="linkfour"><img src="/images/home/imgfour.jpg"</a>', '<a href="linkfive"><img src="/images/home/imgfive.jpg"</a>');
</script>
```

Comment: Where do you want to add the link? What do you expect the link to do?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7260490/image-and-text-inside-of-a-tag check this url.

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not fully answer your question, maybe you can get some ideas from DOM functions.

***Example***

```
<script>

  // Creates Image
  var image = document.createElement("img");

  // Sets Image Attributes
  image.src = "http://i.imgur.com/gqdqudn.png";
  image.width = "30";
  image.height = "30";

  // Adds Image to Body
  document.body.appendChild(image);

</script>
```

This appends an image to the body. If you would like to add it to a specific ID, you could do the following (assuming your div id is "destination").

***Example***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

  <div id="destination">

    <!-- Destination Div -->

  </div>

<script>

  // Creates Image
  var image = document.createElement("img");

  // Sets Image Attributes
  image.src = "http://i.imgur.com/gqdqudn.png";
  image.width = "30";
  image.height = "30";

  // Adds Image to Body
  document.getElementById("destination").appendChild(image);

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Good luck!